# How to get back to previous view from AppDelegate?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm wondering if it's either possible to detect a change in network connection from any screen without using the AppDelegate class or to get back to the previous after changing views from the AppDelegate class ?

Currently I'm using AppDelegate to display an alert when a network connection is detected and tapping OK changes the view to a new view, but from the new view i can't go back to the previous view when tapping the back button in the navigation bar.

AppDelegate doesn't allow me to push views using something like

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:reviewCtrl animated:YES];
```

How can you get back to the previous view where the alert was displayed?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>  I'm wondering if it's either possible to detect a change in network connection from
>  any screen without using the AppDelegate
> ```

yes it is possible using Reachability,

this is documentation https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html

and these are some useful links:

https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-detecting-network-changes-with-reachability/

Answer (score 0):

It would make sense for you to write a `UIViewController` Category to handle the alert. Something like:

```
// UIViewController+NetworkChangeHandler.h
@interface UIViewController(NetworkChangeHandler)

- (void) networkChanged;

@end

// UIViewController+NetworkChangeHandler.m
@implementation UIViewController(NetworkChangeHandler)

- (void) networkChanged {
// display an alert

#if DEBUG
if (!self.navigationController) {
    NSLog(@"No navigation controller for %@", NSStringFromClass([self class]);
    return;
}
#endif

[self.navigationController pushViewController:someViewController animated:yesOrNo];
```

With the Category, you can call networkChanged on any UIViewController (you probably want the topmost) from your AppDelegate when the change is detected.